# How to add caption one image one caption with vertical image?

Tags: html, image

that my code:

```
 <figure>
      <img src="url_image">
      <img src="url_image">
      <img src="url_image">
       <figcaption style='width: 150px; text-align: center;'>ghjghjghj.</figcaption>
    </figure>
```

how to add caption one image one caption with vertical image??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I'm understanding your question. Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do please. If my understanding is correct you're trying to add the caption to the first image?

see here for more information on figcaptions and fig images http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp

you can apply css to style the caption and image as you would wish.